# SQL - Search text for a placeholder, retrieve x characters after

Tags: sql, oracle

I have XML stored in an Oracle database, and I need to extract some text within the XML that is held in between " " after the text "checkbox label=".

For example, in the XML:

```
  <xv:checkbox label="CheckBox 01" />
  <xv:checkbox label="CheckBox 02" />
  <xv:checkbox label="CheckBox 03" />
```

I need my query to extract the following, and place it in a variable.

- CheckBox 01
- CheckBox 02
- CheckBox 03

I really have no idea how to do this, so would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to manually parse XML, it will not end well.
Instead, use one of the many XML features that comes with Oracle such as [XMLTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm), [XMLQUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions224.htm), or [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions051.htm).